# How can i fix Gridview items overlap issue?

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I am getting a image folder from mobile phone using my application and shows in my application with his folder name but some folders have a big name. 
Because of this grid view items overlaps.

this is my xml grid view item file which i am using in grid view layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="@dimen/size_5"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_approval_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_approval_heigh"
    android:id="@+id/approval_images_view"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_approval_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_5"
        android:id="@+id/folder_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_folder"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image_approval_gallery"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_sd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_approval_gallery"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/folder_icon"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_sd" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/tick_image_gallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:buttonTint="@color/bg_o"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/directory_name"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_directory_name"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

[image]

Comment: post your xml layout

Comment: what is @dimen/size_approval_width and @dimen/size_approval_heigh ?

Comment: @dimen/size_approval_width layout width and @dimen/size_approval_heigh layout height

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. pass single line true into last textview.because text it long then it go to next line.

```
    <TextView
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/directory_name"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_directory_name"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    />
```

Comment: can i not solve this issue without  SingleLine. i want to show full name.